# Javascript popup to show file content while php is loading

Tags: javascript, php

How to code javascript to open a popup box and update and display particular file content from local machine repeatedly(since file contents gets keep on change after some time) until php finishes loading.
If PHP finishes loading , the popup has to disappear automatically and redirect to another page.

Comment: did you try anything ..?

Comment: I tried to search in google , I did not found suitable solution thats why asked in stackoverflow. Can you provide me solution to how to read a file from local machine and display it until php loads

Comment: you want to show remaining time or simply `loader image` or `text message` ..?

Comment: I have a file whose content will get updated each time what shell script is doing until it finishes.I need to display users the file content while php looks for the some content is available or not at the some directories.